# Showing that every nonstandard model of arithmetic contains an infinite element

Tags: logic, solution-verification, first-order-logic

I am not quite sure how to prove this. Well, if $\mathfrak{N}$ is the standard model of arithmetic then by definition, a nonstandard model of arithmetic $\mathfrak{N}'$ must be elementarily equivalent to $\mathfrak{N}$ but not isomorphic to $\mathfrak{N}$.

The sentence $(\forall x)( \exists y)(x<y)$ is true in $\mathfrak{N}$ and so it must be true in $\mathfrak{N}'$ as well. But then how will I find a element $b$ in the universe of $\mathfrak{N}'$ such that $a<^{\mathfrak{N}'}b$ for each $a$ in the universe of $\mathfrak{N}'$?

I'm not sure how to proceed. Hints will be appreciated.

---

Here's my attempt after receiving hints from [Asaf Karagila](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/622/asaf-karagila) and [Rob Arthan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/23171/rob-arthan)
:

Let $N$ be the set of Peano Axioms (see [Example 2.8.3](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Mathematical_Logic_and_Proof/Book%3A_Friendly_Introduction_to_Mathematical_Logic_(Leary_and_Kristiansen)/02%3A_Deductions/2.08%3A_Nonlogical_Axioms)). Let $\mathfrak{N}$ be the standard model of arithmetic and $\mathfrak{N}'$ be a nonstandard model of arithmetic. Let $\overline{n}$ be the $\mathcal{L}_{NT}$ term given by $\overline{n}=\underbrace{SS\ldots S}_{n \text{ many}}0$. Let $\Sigma=\{ x=0 \vee x=\overline{1} \vee\ldots\vee x=\overline{n} \vee  \overline{n}<x : n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}\}$. Let $A$ be the universe of $\mathfrak{N}'$

**Claim 1.** . For each $n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$, $N\vdash x<\overline{n} \leftrightarrow x=0 \vee x=\overline{1} \vee \ldots \vee x=\overline{n-1} $.

*Proof of Claim 1.* We proceed by induction on $n$. Consider the case when $n=1$. We have to prove that $N\vdash x<S0\leftrightarrow x=0$. To prove this, we use Quantifier Axioms and 10th Axiom of Peano Axioms (see [Example 2.8.3](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Mathematical_Logic_and_Proof/Book%3A_Friendly_Introduction_to_Mathematical_Logic_(Leary_and_Kristiansen)/02%3A_Deductions/2.08%3A_Nonlogical_Axioms)). We have $N\vdash x<S0 \leftrightarrow x<0 \vee x=0$. But then by the 9th Axiom, $N\vdash \neg x<0$. So by Propositional Consequence, $N\vdash x<S0 \leftrightarrow x=0$ which is what we wanted.

Assume that we already have $N\vdash x<\overline{n} \leftrightarrow x=0 \vee x=\overline{1} \vee \ldots \vee \overline{n-1} $ for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$. Let's prove that $N\vdash x<\overline{n+1} \leftrightarrow x=0 \vee x=\overline{1} \vee \ldots \vee x=\overline{n} $.

Now, $N\vdash x<\overline{n+1}\leftrightarrow x=\overline{n} \vee x<\overline{n}$ by the 10th Axiom and Quantifier Axiom. By Propositional Consequence and Induction hypothesis, we have what we wanted to prove.

**Claim 2.** For each $\sigma \in \Sigma$, $N \vdash \sigma$.

*Proof of Claim 2.* Let $n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$. We show that $N\vdash x=0 \vee x=\overline{1} \vee\ldots\vee x=\overline{n} \vee  \overline{n}<x$. By Axiom 11 and Quantifier Axioms, $N \vdash x<\overline{n} \vee x =\overline{n} \vee \overline{n}<x$. It is easy to see that Claim 1 and Propositional Consequence complete the proof of Claim 2.

**Claim 3.** $A\setminus \{ \underbrace{S^{\mathfrak{N}'}(S^{\mathfrak{N}'}(\ldots S^{\mathfrak{N}'}}_{n \text{ times}}(0^{\mathfrak{N}'})\ldots)) : n \ge 0 \}$ is nonempty for otherwise $\mathfrak{N}\simeq \mathfrak{N}'$.

(Proof of Claim 3 is pretty long but straightforward, so, I will not prove it here).

Now, $\mathfrak{N}\models \Sigma$ and since $\mathfrak{N}'$ is elementarily equivalent to $\mathfrak{N}$, we have $\mathfrak{N}'\models \Sigma$. Let $a$ be any nonstandard element of $\mathfrak{N}'$ (Claim 3 proves the existence of such an element). Let $s$ be any variable assignment function into $\mathfrak{N}'$ which sends $x$ to $a$.
Then for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\mathfrak{N}' \models x=0 \vee x=\overline{1} \vee\ldots\vee x=\overline{n} \vee  \overline{n}<x$. So it must be that $\underbrace{S^{\mathfrak{N}'}(S^{\mathfrak{N}'}(\ldots S^{\mathfrak{N}'}}_{n \text{ times}}(0^{\mathfrak{N}'})\ldots)) <^{\mathfrak{N}'} a$ for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, normally when we say "model of arithmetic" we mean a model of a theory which describes arithmetic, e.g. Peano, rather than true arithmetic.

Secondly, note that an "infinite element" is not $0$, or $s0$, or $ss0$, or $sss0$, or $ssss0$, or $sssss0$, and so on and so on (here $s$ is the successor operation).

Suppose that a model *does not* contain an infinite element. Well, it must contain $0$ and $s0$ and $ss0$ and $sss0$ and $ssss0$ and so on and so on. But we just said, that it doesn't contain any *other* elements. So using this, you can now show that it is isomorphic to the standard model.

(Note that your approach is inherently flawed: the statement "$x$ is a non-standard integer" is **not** first-order definable! It is a property of the model, not an internal property of the element.)

Comment: It might be worth adding that $PA$ can prove all statements of the form $\forall x(x = 0 \lor x = 1 \lor \ldots \lor x = n \lor  x > n$ where $n$ means $s^n0$, so a non-standard element has to be greater than all the standard ones and hence is "infinite".

Comment: Can you take a look at the (almost) proof which I've added?